Mistake in an ODE
I am trying to solve this simple ODE
$$
\frac{da}{dt} = c \cdot a(t)^{-l}
$$
which I think that it is easy:
$$
\frac{a^{l+1}}{l+1} = c t +B \Rightarrow a = (At+B')^{\frac{1}{l+1}}
$$
BUT the solution is $a(t) = At^{\frac{1}{l+1}}+B$ and obviously these expressions are not equal.

Where did c go in both versions, it is not an arbitrary constant. Form of yours looks ok to me

Does it matter whether $a(t)$ is a function (as implied by the question) or a number (as implied by the answer)...?

It is a function.

Is $\frac{d}{dt}\left(At^{\frac{1}{l+1}}+B\right)=c\left(At^{\frac{1}{l+1}}+B\right)^{-l}$?
